# Bootstrap nav menu hover color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying one hour to change hover color of nav-menu, but I was not able to do that. I can't find hover attribute in css for the menu.

Here is page:
http://jazbinasolutions.com/rooney

If you hover over the top menu links you will see they are getting white and actually being invisible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you are looking to change:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

You should use a more specific rule to override it:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you maestro that's it. I forget this thing with !important. 
Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome! As a sign if appreciation I would love it if you marked my answer as accepted when you got the time. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is your exact code with specific selectors, you don't (and should not use !important unless totally warranted). You should also consider using custom classes when altering a framework.

See working example in Snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  min-height: 85px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
  padding-top: 22px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-image: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="http://www.jazbinasolutions.com/rooney/images/ElregLogo2.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="kompetanse.html">Kompetanse</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I do believe `!important` is warranted in this case, but yes custom classes is also a way to go, if you don't mind editing the html a bit, and don't need the change on every menu on your site.

Comment: @turbopipp No, I don't believe so as using the right selectors is the way to write CSS in general [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and as for using custom classes, this merely refers to not directly writing over a frameworks core in general which is a separate matter from specificity.

Comment: You managed to sway me. :) I updated my answer with a more specific css rule, but without any need for custom class.